# Loop/for each SELECT and COUNT without a PROCEDURE or FUNCTION

Tags: mysql, function, loops, select, count

I have a problem building/using a loop to know how often a product ranks on a specific criteria (or combination) across shopping sessions.

This is what I have in my DB for example:

```
Session     |   Product     |   Price   |   PriceQuality    |   Promotion   |   Exclusivity
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Session1    |   ProductA    |   50      |       7           |   Yes         |   No              
Session1    |   ProductB    |   40      |       6           |   No          |   Yes
Session1    |   ProductC    |   30      |       8           |   No          |   No
Session1    |   ProductD    |   20      |       9           |   Yes         |   No
Session2    |   ProductA    |   30      |       6           |   No          |   Yes             
Session2    |   ProductB    |   40      |       7           |   No          |   Yes
Session2    |   ProductC    |   20      |       9           |   No          |   No
Session2    |   ProductD    |   50      |       8           |   Yes         |   No
```

What I would like is to have this sort of output for each label that is present:

```
Product     |   Price_countWhenCheapest |   PriceQuality_countWhenHighest   |   Promotion_countWhenYes  |   Exclusivity_countWhenYes    
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
ProductA    |           0               |           0                       |           1               |           1                       
ProductB    |           0               |           0                       |           0               |           2           
ProductC    |           1               |           1                       |           0               |           0           
ProductD    |           1               |           1                       |           2               |           0
```

Note: because I don't have SUPER privileges on the (cloud) DB, I can't use a procedure or function.

> EDIT:

1. If I expand my test DB with a Session (Session3), the columns
   Price_countWhenCheapest and PriceQuality_countWhenHighest don't
   count above 1 (look at output).
2. I have a separate table named Customer that has more info about the Session. E.g. age of the customer or gender from that Session. How can I JOIN this into the output to:
   2.1. Filter (maybe through a WHERE statement) Sessions that only had 'male' Customers
   2.2. Add a (sub)count within e.g. Price_countWhenCheapest named 'Price_countWhenCheapest_male' to find out how many male Customers attended a Session where a Product was Cheapest (and maybe also Price_countWhenCheapest_25 for customers that had an age of 25)

Added Session3 to test DB:

```
Testrow_id  Session Product Price   PriceQuality    Promotion   Exclusivity
1   Session1    ProductA    50  7   Yes No
2   Session1    ProductB    40  6   No  Yes
3   Session1    ProductC    30  8   No  No
4   Session1    ProductD    20  9   Yes No
5   Session2    ProductA    30  6   No  Yes
6   Session2    ProductB    40  7   No  Yes
7   Session2    ProductC    20  9   No  No
8   Session2    ProductD    50  8   Yes No
9   Session3    ProductA    30  6   No  Yes
10  Session3    ProductB    40  7   No  Yes
11  Session3    ProductC    20  9   No  No
12  Session3    ProductD    50  8   Yes No
```

Output for now:

```
Product Price_countWhenCheapest PriceQuality_countWhenHighest   Promotion_countWhenYes  Exclusivity_countWhenYes
ProductA    0   0   1   2
ProductB    0   0   0   3
ProductC    1   1   0   0
ProductD    1   1   3   0
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately MySQL does not support many things I'd normally use, thus
I'm not certain if this will work, but you could try below statement:

```
SELECT
  Product,
  CASE WHEN b.Product IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Price_countWhenCheapest,
  CASE WHEN c.Product IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS PriceQuality_countWhenHighest,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Promotion = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Promotion_countWhenYes,
  SUM(CASE WHEN Exclusivity = 'Yes' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Exclusivity_countWhenYes
FROM tablename a
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product
  FROM tablename
  WHERE Price = (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM tablename)
) b USING ( Product )
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT Product
  FROM tablename
  WHERE PriceQuality = (SELECT MAX(PriceQuality) FROM tablename)
) c USING ( Product )
GROUP BY Product, Price_countWhenCheapest, PriceQuality_countWhenHighest
```

Though, it requires scanning the table more than once and the distinct part isn't really making this query fast.

The trick is to `JOIN` the information about cheapest price and highest price quality with a 1:1 between products, so that it can be included in group by not changing the groups. If you actually need a count, wrap it up with a `SUM()` like I did with the rest and remove those columns from group by.

Comment: Thanks. This is a very complicated statement. I'll give it a try, but will have to figure out what does what.

Comment: You're expanding your question while you didn't even say if my answer solved the initial question ...

Comment: I'm sorry, but as I've tried to explain in 1. the cheapest premium and highest price quality did not work properly. The count of promotion and exclusivity did.